# Flash messages missing in a server rendered page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, flash-message

I have a Rails 6 app (migrated from Rails 5 a while ago) which manages Items and an Overview of those Items. When you update an Item you're redirected to it's Overview.

Therefore in my Items Controller:

```rb
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.update(item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to overview_path, notice: "Item updated." }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to overview_path, alert: "An error happend." }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I had a requirement to provide a simple API to have this functionality on a micro server which cannot manage much, only display stuff, so no JSON or else. It has to be pure HTML.

It works flawlessly, but with one critical problem: the generated HTML doesn't include the flash message. Tho I have `config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash` in config/application.rb.

In the Overview Controller, after the redirect_to, `puts flash.inspect` is empty, and if I add there `flash[:notice] = 'Hooray!'` it shows, so it's not a render problem.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you actually rendering the flash messages on the page? You have not shown us the `html.erb` that would handle this rendering?

Comment: That's a standard rendering which works when you interact directly on the main server. The problem doesn't come from there, it comes from the fact that the `flash` is empty after the redirect_to (which is not the case when you interact on the main server).

Comment: Your infrastructure is very unclear. You said main server and micro server and API that doesn't seem like an API (since it is just rendering HTML?). You still have to render flash messages and you haven't shown that you are doing that. I understand your comment that `flash` is empty but you haven't shown that either.  Can you please clarify the question?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. When you interact with the main server, you get pages with the flash message. What the so-called "API" does, is just getting interactions from the mini-server then generating the related page and sending it to the mini-server. It does that very well, except for the flash message which is missing. How knowing anything else in the process would help?

Comment: To clarify in the Overviews Controller I added:
`def index
  puts flash.inspect`
and get:
`#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x000000012c9f4138 @discard=#<Set: {}>, @flashes={}, @now=nil>`

Comment: I am sorry I still don't understand. Where is the request going? Where are the controllers and views that you don't see the flash message in on the mini-server or the main server? This is what is unclear to me. Is `redirect_to overview_path` passing you back to the main server?

Comment: Let me take it from another angle. If I add `flash[:notice] = 'Horray!'`  in Overviews#index it does show in the HTML sent to the mini-server. The problem is that the relevant flash notice is lost in the redirect_to between Item to Overview. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Best I can figure out from your question is that you're running a rails API server and your controller is an `ActionController::API`. Assuming that's correct you need several things for flash to work.

Flash messages are stored in session cookies, if you don't have that configured, there is no mechanism to transmit them over the redirect:

```rb
# config/application.rb

config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
```

and you have to include flash module to have a `flash` helper and to be able to set flash through `redirect_to` helper:

```rb
class Api::V1::MyController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::Flash

  #...
end
```

You can also inspect your session to see stored flash messages, in case you're curious:

```rb
<%= session[:flash] %>
```

---

> there's no browser involved in generating the page

```rb
<%== flash.notice.inspect %>
<%== session[:flash] %>
```

Without cookies:

```bash
$ curl http://localhost:3000/items -L -d ""
nil
```

With cookies:

```bash
$ curl http://localhost:3000/items -L -d "" -c cookie.txt -b cookie.txt
"CREATED"
{"discard"=>[], "flashes"=>{"notice"=>"CREATED"}}
```

Comment: No, it's not an API server, it only responds to some let's say in this case peculiar requests, and my controller is an `ApplicationController`.

Comment: @gemp so it's a regular rails app, then why you are including `config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash`. also make sure it's not your browser blocking cookies.

Comment: I tried with middleware, thinking it might solve the problem. The thing is: there's no browser involved in generating the page. The main server receives params from the mini-server, generate the page and sends it back.

Comment: @gemp maybe you should show that part as well, because there is nothing for me to go on here. i'm guessing cookie header is ignored when redirect happens.